# Eloquent ORM is generating a bad query

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I created a simple `users` table with `id`, `name`, and a few other fields in my Laravel 4.2. In my controller, I am trying to save user input as a new user record:

```
$user = new User();
$user->fill($input);
$user->fullname = $input['firstname'] . ' ' . $input['lastname'];
$user->save();
```

The system produces a MySQL error because none of the string values are quoted.

E.g.

```
INSERT INTO users (name, ...) VALUES (John, ...)
```

Why would it not quote the value?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I have all required fields set to fillable in my User model:

```
protected $fillable = array('firstname', 'lastname', 'fullname', 'email', 'username', 'birthday', 'gender', 'country', 'city', 'signature', 'confirmed', 'approved');
```

And here is the full error message:

Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (HY000)

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'US' for column 'country' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `users` (`firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `username`, `birthday`, `gender`, `country`, `city`, `signature`, `fullname`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (John, Watson, my@email.com, admin, 11/08/2014, male, US, New York, I am the main admin., John Watson, 2014-11-08 17:02:16, 2014-11-08 17:02:16))
```

**EDIT AGAIN:**

Quoting is not the problem. The actual value is the problem. It's expecting an integer, and I'm providing a string. Sorry for false alarm. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that is the problem? Post the error message that you are you getting...and be sure that your columns set to `fillable` on the `user` model?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I added the full error message in the original post.

Comment: Oh. I now see that it is not exactly the error I thought it was. Sorry. Thank you.

Comment: It's balking at `US` but others are fine. Quotes probably aren't the problem.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. Thank you.

Comment: "The system produces a MySQL error because none of the string values are quoted." Yes, they are. Laravel's debug output just doesn't show it that way. Your error indicates you're trying to insert the string 'US' into the column 'country' but that 'country' is set up as an integer column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you figured out the problem (Comments says that) that the country field expects an `integer` value but `string` given instead, but I'm going to answer on a different thing that is, you are inserting a `fullname` like:

```
$user->fullname = $input['firstname'] . ' ' . $input['lastname'];
```

In this case you can avoid this but can use a `fullname` for example; in your `User` model just declare an `accessor method` like this:

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->firstname . ' ' . $this->lastname;
}
```

This way you can achieve same thing but don't need to use another extra field in your database and you can access the dynamic property like this:

```
echo $SomeUserObject->full_name;
```

Check more on [Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) website.

Comment: That is a very good advice. It is my first attempt in a long time working with a well-organized object-oriented framework, so I completely forgot that I could make an accessor for concatenations, even though that is something I'm supposed to know. Thank you!